# Programatically create a new column by parsing an expression in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
var c1 = "column1"
var c2 = "column2"
var c3 = "column3"
var exprs = "c1*c2+c3"

var df2 = df.withColumn("target_col",expr(exprs))
```

where c1 c2 c3 are columns in df

This code is throwing an error - Is there a way of accomplishing this? exprs can change .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this possible, you'll need to use *string interpolation* as followed :

```
val c1 = "column1"
val c2 = "column2"
val c3 = "column3"
val exprs = s"$c1*$c2+$c3"

val df2 = df.withColumn("target_col",expr(exprs))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because while initializing `exprs` instead of using the values of `c1,c2,c3` you are creating a new string `c1*c2+c3`. As column `c1*c2+c3` doesn't exists hence the error.
You can use [string interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) to construct `exprs`

```
val exprs = s"$c1*$c2+$c3"
```

And then use this exprs in `withColumn`.

```
val df = df.withColumn("target_col",expr(exprs)).
```

I would also suggest you to use `val` instead or `var`.